# Unable to use texT() in a div - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a div tag HTML code as below:

```
<div class="kac-entry kac-select kac-placeholder ng-binding btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleDropdown()" ng-show="shouldShowPlaceholder()" ng-class="{btn: btnStyle, 'btn-primary': btnStyle}">      Add Index Components   </div>
```

When I try to access the element with the following xpaths, I am unable to find the matching node on my web page,

```
//div[text()='Add Index Components']
//div[text()='      Add Index Components   ']
```

Can someone tell me why am I unable to locate the element?

Answer (score 0):

use the below xpath:

```
//div[contains(text(),'Add Index Components')]
```

but make sure, the text is unique otherwise u will get a list of webelement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `normalize-space()` to remove trailing and leading whitespaces before doing comparison :

```
//div[normalize-space(text()) = 'Add Index Components']
```